# Can I send HTML mails in Outlook Web Access?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, outlook-web-app, email

In my organization some of the employees are located elsewhere from headquarters and therefore they are using Outlook Web Access (OWA) to receive and send E-mails.

The problem lies in the format in how E-mails are sending and forwarded. When receiving an E-mail which has HTML context (e.g. tables) it shows it right enough but when the same E-mail is forwarded it completely disturbs the layout and it seems like it can only send in pure text.

Is there any way I can enable HTML to be used for sending and forwarding E-mails through OWA, either via the settings in OWA or our Exchange server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a dropdown box when you create a new message through OWA - the two options are "HTML" and "plain text".  If that box isn't there, there may be a problem with your Client Access server, or someone may have managed to remove it (though I'm not aware of any way to do this).

Comment: Hi,

thank you very much. My problem was that I use Firefox or Chrome instead of IE. I've now installed IE Tab extension for Firefix and it work like a charm. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Oops, I'm guilty of assuming everyone else gave up and just uses IE for OWA, too.  Though I'm pleasantly surprised there was a quick fix for this without having to switch browsers - thanks for posting the follow-up.

Answer (score 1):

The dropdown box, where you can choose "html" or "plain text" is shown when you use firefox. You have to use Internet Explorer to see all the options.

Comment: Did you mean "...is ***not*** shown when you use Firefox"?

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are using IE but still nothing works, Please try below option as it worked for me:

1. Go to Options-->Accessibility --> uncheck -use blind and low vision experience
2. Close IE and login again

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [Kara Marfia](https://serverfault.com/users/1803/kara-marfia) above, you can choose what message type to create when you click on new message.

If you want to make the switch permanent, like I did, then this is likely more useful:

---

1. Click on the settings button on the top-right corner and **select Options**.

[image]

2. **Select Settings** from the left hand window pane and **click on the Mail tab**.
3. **Scroll down** to Message format section, you can now **set message format** to HTML or Plain text from the drop down list.

[image]

---

Taken near verbatim from https://www.ucl.ac.uk/isd/how-to/email-calendar/html-plain-text-messages-owa